# creating a formatted array using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this array in the format.

```js
var data = [{
  "Month": "Jan 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "Jan 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "Feb 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "Feb 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "Mar 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "April 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "May 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "May 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "June 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "July 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "Aug 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "Sept 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "Oct 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "Nov 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "Dec 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}, {
  "Month": "Dec 2017 - Check",
  "balance": "0.00"
}]
var label = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var label1 = [];
  var label1 = [];
  label1.push(data[i].Month.split('-')[0].trim().split(" ").join(','));
  label.push(label1);

}

console.log(label)
```

And I want to get the format

```
[
    ["June", "2015"], "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", ["January", "2016"], "February", "March", "April", "May"
]
```

What I want is for array with space to be in another array. Reason for this is that I will use in chartJS.

What I get so far is

```
[
  [
    "Jan,2017,-,Check"
  ]
]
```

This should look like

```
[
  [
    "Jan","2017","-","Check"
  ]
]
```

Please ignore the `- Check` I will trim it but I have still error for now if there element is not `.trim()` My focus is create the same format of array

Comment: I don't see the pattern. How did you get `2015` in `["June", "2015"]`? You need to provide more info.

Comment: @Mikey this one `"July 2017 - Check"` i will trim it using `.split('-')[0]` getting `July 2017` and then I want to get `["July","2017"]` but what I get is `["July,2017"]` I hope this is clear please comment if not

Comment: Agreed. Please show the same data in the source and desired blocks. Also you say it should look like "Jan","2017","-","Check"  but ignore the check?

Comment: @Mikey I have updated the OP so that it will be same

Comment: @JasonB I have updated the OP so that it will be same

Comment: Kindly update the question once more with the desired array **based off** the source array that you provided. There is no 2015 in your source array, so there should be no 2015 in your desired array. That in itself already causes confusion. Also, why is your desired array a mix of arrays e.g. `["July,2017"]` and strings e.g. `"July"`? What determines if the element should be an 2-piece array vs a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` for this.

Here is a fiddle:

```js
var data = [{
    "Month": "Jan 2017 - Check",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "Jan",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "Feb 2017 - Check",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "Feb",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "Mar",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "April",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "May 2017 - Check",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "May",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "June",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "July 2017 - Check",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "Aug",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "Sept",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "Oct 2017 - Check",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "Nov 2017 - Check",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "Dec 2017 - Check",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }, {
    "Month": "Dec",
    "balance": "0.00"
  }];
  
  
  var result = data.map(function(v,i){
   let month = v.Month.split(" ");
   
   if ( month.length == 1 ) return month[0];
   else return [ month[0],month[1] ];
  });
  
  console.log( result );
```

Comment: give me a minute I check the compatibility in my source

Comment: I have last question for the trim Example I have `qwe - July - Checked` and `qwe - July(e-status) - Check` my trim fails because there is another `-` my trim is like `v.Month.split("-")[1].trim().split(" ")` the second `-` is getting trim too when I need to get the `July(e-status)`

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to achieve. This is not on that you desired output on your post.

Comment: it should be there but it is confusing sample string is `qwe - July(e-status) 2017 - Check` now I need to get `"July(e-status)", "2017"` right? but when I do my split of string using the code `v.Month.split("-")[1].trim().split(" ")` it will fail because there is another `-` I want to trim only `-` that is between space how to do it trim?

Comment: What is `qwe`? Why do you have to `split("-")`?

Comment: it is just a sample string there should be a string there the department basically I only need the middle part of the string but I need to include `e-status` part but since it has `-` it gets trimmed also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163678/discussion-between-eddie-and-giant).

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQUERY for this.

Here is a fiddle:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


           $(document).ready(function () {


               var data = [{
                   "Month": "Jan 2017 - Check",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "Jan",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "Feb 2017 - Check",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "Feb",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "Mar",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "April",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "May 2017 - Check",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "May",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "June",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "July 2017 - Check",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "Aug",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "Sept",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "Oct 2017 - Check",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "Nov 2017 - Check",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "Dec 2017 - Check",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }, {
                   "Month": "Dec",
                   "balance": "0.00"
               }];

               var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

               var JsonObject = JSON.parse(myJsonString);
               var label = [];
               var myJsonStrings = null;
               $.each(data, function (k, v) {

                   var label1 = [];
                   if (v.Month.includes("-")) {
                       label1.push(v.Month.split(" - Check").join(''));
                       label.push(label1);
                   }
                   else {
                       label.push(v.Month.split(" ").join(','));
                   }
                   //console.log(k + ' is ' + v.Month);
                   //console.log(label);
                    myJsonStrings = JSON.stringify(label);

               });
               console.log(myJsonStrings);
           });

    </script>
```